# Missing outer border of the table

Tags: tables

I have a table where the last column has no border at the right side.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{booktabs}


    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{booktabs,array}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

    \DeclareMathOperator\prb{probability}
    \DeclareMathOperator\cost{cost}
    \DeclareMathOperator\child{child}

    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
    \begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \label{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \begin{tabular}{ |m{2cm}| m{2.5cm} | m{2cm}|m{2cm}| m{2cm} | }
    \hline
    ID  &  cost  &  severity & probability & risk  \\ 
    \hline
        C1      &  300   &  8    & 0.5 \\
     \hline
        C2      &  200   &  8    & 0.5
    \\ \hline
        C1 and C2        &  500= 300 + 200   &  8   & 0.5
    \\ \hline
        T1     &  300    &  8    & 0.5
    \\ \hline
        T2     &  300    &  8    & 0.5
    \\ \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

So, **why i don't have any any border on the column?**

Comment: What class do you use? I don't have it, though I have full TexLive-2017 installed. Please, when you post an MWE, use standart classes, exclude packages you do not need and commands you do not use.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Just use `article`, the class is not relevant here.

Comment: you have forgotten to put `&` in the last so thats why last vertical line is missing @Salman

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek  yes, article works, but it is more a recommendation for OP, who violates the rules of MWE not for the first time.

Comment: http://www.eve.phys.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/tqc2012/doc/llncs.cls @MichaelFraiman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line right is set by the leftmost cell, which is omitted in most of the rows.
Fixed:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \label{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \begin{tabular}{ |m{2cm}| m{2.5cm} | m{2cm}|m{2cm}| m{2cm} | }
    \hline
    ID  &  cost  &  severity & probability & risk  \\
    \hline
        C1      &  300   &  8    & 0.5 & \\
     \hline
        C2      &  200   &  8    & 0.5 &
    \\ \hline
        C1 and C2        &  500= 300 + 200   &  8   & 0.5 &
    \\ \hline
        T1     &  300    &  8    & 0.5 &
    \\ \hline
        T2     &  300    &  8    & 0.5 &
    \\ \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, you have loaded package `booktabs` twice. Why are you not using it?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \label{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
   \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    \toprule
    ID  &  Cost  &  Severity & Probability & Risk  \\
    \midrule
        C1      &  300   &  8    & 0.5 & \\
        C2      &  200   &  8    & 0.5 & \\
        C1 and C2        &  $500 = 300 + 200$ &  8   & 0.5 & \\
        T1     &  300    &  8    & 0.5 & \\
        T2     &  300    &  8    & 0.5 & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with booktabs]

Answer (score 1):

When you creating a table, you have to use so many "&" as the columns defined in the "{ |m{2cm}| m{2.5cm} | m{2cm}|m{2cm}| m{2cm} | }" minus one...

Here you have defined a table with 5 columns and in your code you have only 3 separators of column (&)... Thus the last column is missing and latex decides to ignore all the last column including in its exception the last "|"...

By adding a last "&" before the line break "\" of every row of your tabular the error is fixed as you can see in @Heiko Oberdiek's answer...

Also you have to be careful with multicolumn:

See the next code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\DeclareMathOperator\prb{probability}
\DeclareMathOperator\cost{cost}
\DeclareMathOperator\child{child}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Countermeasure solutions for connected vehicle}
  \label{tab:CountSolfCV}
  \begin{tabular}{ |m{2cm}| m{2.5cm} | m{2cm}|m{2cm}| m{2cm} | }
    \hline
    ID  &  cost  &  severity & probability & risk  \\ 
    \hline
    C1      &  300   &  8    & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{0.5} \\
    \hline
    C2      &  200   &  8    & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}|}{0.5}
    \\ \hline
    C1 and C2        &  500= 300 + 200   &  8   & \multicolumn{2}{|p{4cm}}{0.5}
    \\ \hline
    T1     &  300    &  8    & \multicolumn{2}{|p{4cm}|}{ 0.5}
    \\ \hline
    T2     &  300    &  8    & 0.5 &
    \\ \hline  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

See the picture bellow

[image]

The correct way for multicolumn is the second row after the labels of the values because the previous column has it's own "|" and if you add one more it will doubleprinted as it does in the next two rows which seems to be correct if you don't know what exactly happens.

PS: The labels of the tables, figures etc... are made to make our life easier on referring to the table or the figure... It's better to use a small and "characteristic" label.